Designing complex mixed model analysis
I'm trying to analyze EEG data from patients using mixed models.. and I've been stuck on this for a while, I've read a bunch of papers and a primer textbook on it but still not sure what I'm doing.. I'm trying to use statsmodels in python to do this.
There are 10 subjects, and each have their brain waves recorded during a session. Each session has a 'control' state where they do nothing and a state where they are watching some video (treatment). There are multiple sessions, and some subjects have skipped some of the sessions. The brain activity is localized to particular areas in the brain.
With mixed models, the measures are repeated for a single subject for the different sessions (time) but also for treatment vs control.. here starts my confusion - when both time and treatment condition are within a single subject (?nested?) how do I deal with the complication in the analysis? My very simplistic understanding of mixed models is that there is a repeated measure (e.g. brain activity at a certain location) and there are subjects that undergo either treatment or control, but not both.. is there literature that specifically deals with this issue?
The other question gives me even more of a headache - I'm not sure if I should perform the analysis separately for each brain area or brain area should be an independent variable. If I have it as an IV (brain activity in different areas is unlikely to be independent, as part of the thesis is that certain areas are connected).. I guess that makes the design of the statistical analysis even more complicated. Then another IV may be the different brain wave frequency bands (alpha vs beta vs theta etc), and similar question applies - to analyze separately or not, since they may also be not independent.. I'm a very confused soul here and would appreciate a nudge in the right direction..
Thank you profusely

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In theory, you can utilize a mixed model for your data. I am not sure about the data conversion process for EEG and what form the signal output variable takes. This would determine what type of mixed model you would run. If it is continuous in nature, you would use a linear mixed model, if it is something else, you will need to use a generalized linear mixed model.
With regards to your first issue, the fact that individuals have both a "control" and "treatment" condition in each session, this is not a problem at all. This means that you have what is sometimes called a within-subjects design. You need to include a 0/1 indicator as a predictor in your model so that your model knows when the subject is in the control or treatment condition. The coefficient on that predictor indicates the average difference in the EEG signal strength between treatment and control occasions. You may want to push on this further by allowing this slope to vary across individual subjects, but that will be up to you. Another thing you may want to consider is to include a variable in the model that indicates which session the data comes from for a given subject. There are so many ways to go with this, honestly. You should consult with someone who has worked in this area.
As to your second issue, you have at least two options. If you believe that one of the brain regions measured is more likely to drive the signal in another region, then you would likely include the signal from the driver region as a predictor in your model. If, on the other hand, you do not have a prior reason to believe that one region is driving the responses of another region, then you could estimate a multivariate version of the original model. I do not believe there is a statsmodel version of such a model so you may either need to program it yourself or consider using a Bayesian approach through something like pymc or PyStan. Certainly you can do this in R using something like brms(). See here for the brms() implementation.
